# Flash GetVariable without ActiveX

Tags: flash, activex

It looks like the (deprecated)`GetVariable` JS function works only when ActiveX is enabled in the browser.

How can I use the `GetVariable` function in non-ActiveX browsers such as Chrome and Firefox?

(I can't use `ExternalInterfaces`.)

Comment: Are you hacking into a swf and do not have the source code? Is that why you can not use ExternalInterface?